# how to pass data to function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

Hy,

it is ok when I pass data to `<weather [coords]=coords></weather>` where "receiving" template has `{{coords}}`. 
But what if I want to pass data to function `getForecast(coords: string): void` and show weekly weather with dynamic list, but not just to bind my coords? I want coords to be manipulated. Can you help me?

Weather component:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let wfc of WeeklyForecast">
                <div>{{wfc.time}}</div>
                <div><img src="{{wfc.icon}}" /></div>
 </ng-container>
```

Expect:
function `getForecast(coords: string): void` takes coords and "saves" result to `this.WeeklyForecast`

Comment: Please do more clarify you'r question.

Comment: @Arash I want to not just to bind the data, but to pass it to function to look for weather using function and output dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference to your component to call the function:

**Component template:**

`<weather></weather>`

**script:**

```
@ViewChild(WeatherComponent) weatherComponent;
this.weatherComponent.getForecast(coords: string);
```

**Edit**

In response to your question about alternatives: you can get in between the @Input functionality and call your function there.

Pseudo-code (maybe):

```
_coords;
@Input set coords(val) {
  this._coords = val;
  // Call your function
}
get coords() {
    return this._coords;
}
```

Comment: ok, I get your mind. But my idea is to pass the data like attributes `[coords]=coords` without creating extra  functionalities? Is it only way you have just suggested?